# Show that $\int_0^1\int_0^1\frac{\left[-\ln(x)\right]^s\left[-\ln(y)\right]^t}{1-xy}dxdy=\frac{\Gamma(s+t+1)\zeta(s+t+2)}{s+t \choose t}$

Tags: integration

the value of the binomial coefficients for nonnegative n and k is given by $${n\choose k}=\frac{n!}{k!(n-k)!}$$

For n is a positive integer the gamma function is defined for $\Gamma(n)=(n-1)!$

For Re(s)>1 the zeta functions is defined as 
$$\zeta(s)=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{1}{(n+1)^s}$$

How do you evaluate and by what methods to tackle this double integral?

$$\int_0^1\int_0^1\frac{\left[-\ln(x)\right]^s\left[-\ln(y)\right]^t}{1-xy}dxdy=\frac{\Gamma(s+t+1)\zeta(s+t+2)}{s+t \choose t}$$

Where (s,t)$\ge 0$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Through the substitutions $x=e^{-u},y=e^{-v}$ we get:
$$  I(s,t)=\iint_{(0,+\infty)^2} \frac{u^s v^t}{e^{u+v}-1}\,du\,dv =\iint_{(0,+\infty)^2}u^s v^t\sum_{n\geq 1}e^{-nu}e^{-nv}\,du\,dv$$
so, by Fubini's theorem and the fact that $\int_{0}^{+\infty}t^a e^{-nt}\,dt = \frac{a!}{n^{a+1}}$ we get:
$$ I(s,t) = \sum_{n\geq 1}\frac{s! t!}{n^{s+t+2}} =s!\cdot t!\cdot \zeta(s+t+2)$$
as wanted.